# gdalbuildvrt vs gdal_merge on overlapping images

Tags: gdal, osgeo4w, gdal-merge, gdalbuildvrt

I once have used gdalbuildvrt on georeferenced images. That was okay when images did not overlap, It was also time efficient compared to gdal_merge or gdal_warp. Now I have overlapping images and gdalbuildvrt is a little problematic to me. Let me explain:
For the testing purposes I have one image named 0.jpg(1600*900). I use the following command to georeference 0.jpg.

```
gdal_translate -a_srs EPSG:4326 -co interleave=pixel -a_ullr -180.0 90.0 180.0 -90.0 0.jpg ONE.tif
```

To see how it will merge overlapping areas I type the following:

```
gdal_translate -a_srs EPSG:4326 -co interleave=pixel -a_ullr -90.0 90.0 90.0 -90.0 0.jpg TWO.tif
```

So what I expect when I merge ONE.tif and TWO.tif is TWO.tif fills the center of the picture. Finally, I use gdalbuildvrt on these two:`gdalbuildvrt -input_file_list LIST.txt ONETWO.vrt`, and then `gdal_translate ONETWO.vrt ONETWO.tif`

My LIST.txt consists of two lines: first ONE.tif then TWO.tif.
The problem is here. 0.jpg was 1600*900 pixels. So I expect ONETWO.tif to be 1600*900 pixels-- ONE.tif covering from -180 to +180, and TWO.tif overwriting from -90 to +90. Although TWO.tif covers the center in the result, the final image is 2133*900 pixels. Why is this happening?  Of course,  I can use -outsize on gdal_translate to restore the original resolution but I am not sure if it is the right way to solve this.

On the other hand, gdal_merge is also an alternative, giving me what I want(not changing the original resolution) but it is likely that it will take longer compared to gdalbuildvrt.

I use GDAL 2.2.0, released on 2017/04/28 on OSGeo4W64. 
Below is an example information stored in ONETWO.vrt. It is probably this area that needs to get modified.

`<VRTRasterBand dataType="Byte" band="1">
    <ColorInterp>Red</ColorInterp>
    <SimpleSource>
      <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="1">ONE.tif</SourceFilename>
      <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
      <SourceProperties RasterXSize="1600" RasterYSize="900" DataType="Byte" BlockXSize="1600" BlockYSize="1" />
      <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="1600" ySize="900" />
      <DstRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="2133.33333333333" ySize="900" />
    </SimpleSource>
    <SimpleSource>
      <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="1">TWO.tif</SourceFilename>
      <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
      <SourceProperties RasterXSize="1600" RasterYSize="900" DataType="Byte" BlockXSize="1600" BlockYSize="1" />
      <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="1600" ySize="900" />
      <DstRect xOff="533.333333333333" yOff="0" xSize="1066.66666666667" ySize="900" />
    </SimpleSource>
  </VRTRasterBand>`

Why are the destination coordinates messed up like 533.3333 or 2133.3333? And, is there a way to use gdalbuildvrt on overlapping images just like gdal_merge?

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me. Which gdal version? What if you change ONE.tif>DstRect>xSize from 2133.33333333333 to 1600. And TWO.tif>DstRect>xOff from 533.3333 to 400 and xSize from 1066.66666666667 to 800?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should read again the document page or gdalbuildvrt http://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html. Pay attention to parameter called "resolution"

> -**resolution** {highest|lowest|average|user}:
>
> In case the resolution of all input files is not the same, the -resolution flag enables the user to control the way the output resolution is computed. 'average' is the default. 'highest' will pick
>   the smallest values of pixel dimensions within the set of source
>   rasters. 'lowest' will pick the largest values of pixel dimensions
>   within the set of source rasters. 'average' will compute an average of
>   pixel dimensions within the set of source rasters. 'user' is new in
>   GDAL 1.7.0 and must be used in combination with the -tr option to
>   specify the target resolution.

With your workflow you can verify with gdalinfo that the image ONE.tif has pixel size

> Pixel Size = (0.2250,-0.2000)

and TWO.tif has pixel size

> Pixel Size = (0.1125,-0.2000)

By running gdalbuildvrt with setting -resolution parameter either to "**average**" which is the default, "**highest**", or "**lowest**", you will get a .vrt file with pixel size of the first axis either 0.16875, 0.1125, or 0.2250, respectively.

You wrote "giving me what I want(not changing the original resolution)" but it is not possible because you have two different original resolutions in your source data.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. What I meant by "original resolution" should have been "size". In my case "-resolution lowest" has worked if anyone wonders .

Comment: Also, I always took resolution as in "screen resolution", like 1600*900--just two numbers denoting how many pixels there are. With that in my mind I thought my input files had the same resolution, and I had nothing to do with -resolution flag. But georeferencing affects the resolution after all, I understand that now, thanks.